# Color legend in Y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, color, legend

I have the following multiple y-axis plot that results in the image on the top image. However, I want to add a sort of legend in each of the Y axis, similar to what I manually drew in the bottom image. Any idea how can I add color tags into the Y axis labels?

[image] [image]

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
grid=major,grid style={dashed},
width=3in,
height=3in,
scale only axis,
xmin=2,
xmax=21,
separate axis lines,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.02,
ytick       ={    0, 0.005,  0.01, 0.015,  0.02},
ylabel      ={Maximun displacement error},
yticklabels ={    0, 0.005,  0.010, 0.015,  0.020},
xtick       ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21},
xticklabels ={0.00,,,,,0.005,,,,,0.010,,,,,0.015,,,,,0.020},
%xtick      ={0,2.5,5,7.5,10,12.5,15,17.5,20,21},
%xticklabels    ={0.00,,0.005,,0.010,,0.015,,0.020,},
]
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
line width=2.0pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0\\
2 0\\
3 0.00199752\\
4 0.00299752\\
5 0.00399893\\
6 0.00499837\\
7 0.00599192\\
8 0.00699623\\
9 0.00799115\\
10 0.00899543\\
11 0.00999383\\
12 0.0109399\\
13 0.0119664\\
14 0.0129645\\
15 0.0139899\\
16 0.0148372\\
17 0.0159921\\
18 0.0164528\\
19 0.0179454\\
20 0.018987\\
21 0.0197936\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3in,
height=3in,
scale only axis,
xmin=2,
xmax=21,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
ytick={   0, 0.25,  0.5, 0.75,    1},
yticklabels ={    0$\%$, 25$\%$,  50$\%$, 75$\%$,  100$\%$},
ylabel={Percentatge of corrected area},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=right,
xtick={},
xticklabels={},
]
\addplot [
color=green,
solid,
line width=2.0pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 1\\
2 1\\
3 0.904386951631046\\
4 0.526809148856393\\
5 0.314585676790401\\
6 0.202474690663667\\
7 0.182602174728159\\
8 0.164604424446944\\
9 0.142482189726284\\
10 0.0941132358455193\\
11 0.0761154855643045\\
12 0.0712410948631421\\
13 0.0663667041619797\\
14 0.0626171728533933\\
15 0.0543682039745032\\
16 0.0284964379452568\\
17 0.0273715785526809\\
18 0.0269966254218223\\
19 0.0232470941132358\\
20 0.0213723284589426\\
21 0.0206224221972253\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: When I've done this, if it's really just 1 series per axis, I've changed the text colour of the y axis labels.  IMO it looks nicer (though not with that bright green on screen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\label` and `\ref` functionality that PGFPlots provides for putting legend images in your axis labels: Put `\label{<some text>}` after each of the `\addplot` commands, and `\ref{<some text>}` in the `ylabel` text. That way, the legend image will stay synchronised with the color and style of the plot lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
grid=major,grid style={dashed},
width=3in,
height=3in,
scale only axis,
xmin=2,
xmax=21,
separate axis lines,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.02,
ytick       ={    0, 0.005,  0.01, 0.015,  0.02},
ylabel      ={\ref{displacementplot} Maximum displacement error},
yticklabels ={    0, 0.005,  0.010, 0.015,  0.020},
xtick       ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21},
xticklabels ={0.00,,,,,0.005,,,,,0.010,,,,,0.015,,,,,0.020},
%xtick      ={0,2.5,5,7.5,10,12.5,15,17.5,20,21},
%xticklabels    ={0.00,,0.005,,0.010,,0.015,,0.020,},
]
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
line width=2.0pt,
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0\\
2 0\\
3 0.00199752\\
4 0.00299752\\
5 0.00399893\\
6 0.00499837\\
7 0.00599192\\
8 0.00699623\\
9 0.00799115\\
10 0.00899543\\
11 0.00999383\\
12 0.0109399\\
13 0.0119664\\
14 0.0129645\\
15 0.0139899\\
16 0.0148372\\
17 0.0159921\\
18 0.0164528\\
19 0.0179454\\
20 0.018987\\
21 0.0197936\\
}; \label{displacementplot}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3in,
height=3in,
scale only axis,
xmin=2,
xmax=21,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
ytick={   0, 0.25,  0.5, 0.75,    1},
yticklabels ={    0$\%$, 25$\%$,  50$\%$, 75$\%$,  100$\%$},
ylabel={\ref{areaplot} Percentage of corrected area},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=right,
xtick={},
xticklabels={},
]
\addplot [
color=green,
solid,
line width=2.0pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 1\\
2 1\\
3 0.904386951631046\\
4 0.526809148856393\\
5 0.314585676790401\\
6 0.202474690663667\\
7 0.182602174728159\\
8 0.164604424446944\\
9 0.142482189726284\\
10 0.0941132358455193\\
11 0.0761154855643045\\
12 0.0712410948631421\\
13 0.0663667041619797\\
14 0.0626171728533933\\
15 0.0543682039745032\\
16 0.0284964379452568\\
17 0.0273715785526809\\
18 0.0269966254218223\\
19 0.0232470941132358\\
20 0.0213723284589426\\
21 0.0206224221972253\\
}; \label{areaplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to your `ylabel` a `TikZ` code in this way:

```
ylabel={\tikz\draw[green,fill=green] (0,0) circle (.35em);\ Percentatge of corrected area}
ylabel={\tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (.35em);\ Maximun displacement error}
```

[image]